# How to properly combine static hour and minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have in our table, in SQL Server 2008, the datetime is only holding the date.
There is also an hour col and a minute col, there are for the appointment. the are both columns defined as number.

The hour is typically like this:

```
12.00
```

and minute is like `40.00`. I tried adding them but it gives a total rather than
12:40 which is what we need. How can I get this to show 12:40. With the : would be better.

Comment: what RDMS are you using?

Comment: I am assuming you are using MS SQL  --  If so, this may help? https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12315/SQL-Server-Date-Styles-formats-using-CONVERT.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... taking a shot here, for SQL Server

```
declare @table table (d datetime,h decimal(4,2), m decimal(4,2))
insert into @table
values
('20170113',12.00,40.00),
('20170113',9.00,8.00)

select
    d + cast(left(h,len(floor(h))) + ':' + cast(left(m,len(floor(m))) as varchar(2))  + ':' + '00' as datetime)
from
    @table
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepend `00.` to minutes - please note that dot there.
2. Convert both to times.
3. Add them.
4. Convert result back to string.

This way You will also corectly handle situation like 12.40 + 00.30.00 = 13.10